# Panel onClick handler?

Tags: java, gwt, panel

I have a Horizontal Panel, when I click anywhere in that panel, I want a dialog box to pop up. However, there doesn't seem to be a click handler for this panel. Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HorizontalPanel` has methods `addDomHandler` and `addHandler` which you can use to add `ClickHandler`, e.g.

```
HorizontalPanel panel = new HorizontalPanel();
panel.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // TODO process event
    }
}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

Morning,

you can always add your own Handlers to any panel by calling the `addDomHanlder` method. The `addClickHandler` method sim0pliefies that. Here is some sample code for you:

```
        HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
    hp.add(new Label("samplelabel 1"));
    hp.add(new Label("samplelabel 2"));
    hp.add(new Label("samplelabel 3"));

    ClickHandler ch = new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.alert("clicked");                
        }
    };

    hp.addDomHandler(ch, ClickEvent.getType());

    hp.setWidth("500px");
    hp.setHeight("500px");

    RootPanel.get().add(hp);
```

You can read more on the subject under 'Widget Developers' on [What's New in GWT 1.6?](http://code.google.com/intl/de-AT/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/ReleaseNotes_1_6.html).